# Inverse Fourier of a Discrete and Finite Sampling Window

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, ifft

I am trying to find the inverse Fourier of a discrete sampling window with N_f = 11 elements. I am expecting to see a [periodic Sinc-like signal](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/12/31/discrete-time-fourier-transform-dtft/) in the time-domain:
[image]

However, this is the output I get: 
[image]

Why the number of observed oscillations in my output is more than the expected output?

```
N_f = 11; % Number of samples in the finite sampling window in Frequency domain
delta_f = 1;
f = [-N_f/2+1:delta_f:N_f/2];
wf = ones(1, N_f)/N_f; % W(f):finite sampling window in Frequency Domain
N_t =128;
wt = ifftshift(ifft(wf, N_t))*N_t; % w(t):Inverse Fourier of the window
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo , sorry if I was not clear. I meant **the number** of observed oscillations between two consecutive Sinc. For example, in the expected w(t) on the first figure, there are 4 peaks between the maximums of two Sincs. However in my output, there are 9 peaks.

Comment: Have you written out the formula for the sinc function and counted the zero-crossings? It could be that the zeropadding is making more of them visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the issues with your code is related to the location of the origin. You create an array `wf` with 11 ones (and normalized), then call `ifft(wf,128)`. This pads the array with zeros to a size of 128, but the 11 ones are on the left side. You can see this by doing

```
fft(ifft(wf, N_t))
```

Thus, your window is shifted by 5 samples to the right, covering frequency bins 0 through 11, rather than -5 through 5 (or identically, 0 through 5 and 124 through 128).

The code below creates a signal with 128 samples, and fills the 11 frequency bins around the middle with `1/11`. By calling `ifftshift` we rotate the signal such that the middle element is moved to the leftmost bin. Now bins 0 through 5 and 124 through 128 are non-zero. I then call `ifft`, and `fftshift` to move the 0 frequency back to the middle of the signal. Finally, I plot three repetitions of this signal.

```
N_f = 11; % Number of samples in the finite sampling window in Frequency domain
N_t = 128;
wf = zeros(1,N_t);
wf( N_t/2 - floor(N_f/2) + 1 : N_t/2 + floor(N_f/2) + 1 ) = 1 / N_f;
wt = fftshift(ifft(ifftshift(wf))) * N_t;
figure; plot(repmat(wt,1,3))
```

[image]

As you can see, the result is as you expected it. Note that the `wt` result of `ifft` is actually real-valued. The result of your inverse transform wasn't real-valued, you had to ignore the imaginary component to produce your plot. That's a sign that the input signal wasn't symmetric!

We can change `N_f` to be twice as large, yielding a result similar to yours, but with a purely real output:

```
N_f = 21;
N_t = 128;
wf = zeros(1,N_t);
wf( N_t/2 - floor(N_f/2) + 1 : N_t/2 + floor(N_f/2) + 1 ) = 1 / N_f;
wt = fftshift(ifft(ifftshift(wf))) * N_t;
figure; plot(repmat(wt,1,3))
```

[image]